# Solace Integration with .NET/REST

Tags: solace

I am totally new to Solace, your ideas will be grateful. building a system that will integrate with Solace Messaging bus. the system will have a service layer which will communicate with Solace Messaging bus to pull messages from external systems and in future, it also will be integrate with internet based messages.

So I have two options in front of me, 1) JMS 2) .NET 3) REST

Could you please let me know which is the best option above, when the service layer has to connect with .NET Business layer. considering, extensibility, performance, message transformation, scalability etc.,

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Messages are generally inter-operable between the different APIs.
For example, a JMS message can be consumed by a .NET consumer.

You can pick whichever API is the most convenient for your use case.

Since your service layer is communicating directly with your .NET Business layer, perhaps it might make sense to have the service layer use the .NET API.

Alternatively, you might feel that it makes sense to make use of the REST API, which is an open protocol, without the need for Solace provided libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your response. both options are good. However, the REST API open protocol looks most viable as it can be easily integrated with Message Bus and .NET Business Layer. Could you please let me know, how this REST API can be built

Comment: Please refer to the REST messaging tutorial over at http://dev.solacesystems.com/get-started/rest-tutorials/publish-subscribe_rest/ It provides an example to send and receive messages.